# Why when I subtract from my array nothing happen? How do I get better precision out of python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, precision

I do not know if my problem is just an error in coding or a precision problem.

Basically, I am doing a minimizing problem. I am trying to use a particular algorithm to find the minimizer of a function. The math behind what I'm doing isnt really important, beside the fact that I am trying to subtract [-2.65765056e-22  9.20132910e-23] from [1.2,1,2] and when I do, all I get back is [1.2, 1.2].

I assume this is a precision problem, so I looked for a way to allow for more than 64 bit precision in python it it will not allow me.

I have tried turning everything into a float64 type variable, but that still didnt work. I removed that code for the sake of readability

Please help, I really want to write this in python and not lower myself to using matlab :P (jk).

But seriously, is it my code or the precision or both? 
Can this be done in Python?

here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return 100*(x[0]-x[1]**2)**2+(1-x[0])**2

def df(x):
    return np.array([-400*x[0]*(x[1]-x[0]**2)*x[0]-2*(1-x[0]), 200*(x[1]-x[0]**2)])

def ndf(x):
    return x[0]**2 + x[1]**2



alpha=1
row=.999
c=.5

epsilon =.0004
y=[1.2,1.2]
while ndf(df(y)) > epsilon:
   print(ndf(df(y))) 
   alpha=1 
   while f(y - alpha*df(y)) > f(y)-c*alpha*(ndf(df(y)))**2:

       alpha = row*alpha


   y=y-alpha*df(y)
   print(-alpha*df(y))
   print(y-alpha*df(y))
```

here are the outputs:
[Outputs and variable types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7GaR.png)

As always stack over flow gurus, thank you!

Comment: Subtracting things that are 23 orders of magnitude different is a precision problem.  But I find it highly unlikely that needing to subtract things that are 23 orders of magnitude different is a reasonable thing.  I would look at the algo or the code for the issue, not the precision.

Comment: Re-implement everything using `decimal.Decimal` objects. This allows for arbitrary precision (as long as you got the memory)

Comment: Beaten to it. If you're trying to subtract this magnitude of values then I really wonder what this algorithm does. It isn't going to shift a value noticeably in your lifetime, floating point issues aside.

Comment: I am pretty sure my algorithm is correct. Just pored over it again. It is the gradient descent algorithm using the backtracking line search

Comment: Also, i know the exact answer it is [1,1] so the algorithm doesn't have to go very far.  How do I use decimal.Decimal with arrays?

Comment: The algorithm has to go a _long_ way if it's moving in those increments. Something doesn't sound right here. Don't bother with `Decimal`, something else is not right

Comment: Okay you are all right. there is def something wrong with my algorithm. I found some errors, but i am still having trouble with the bit of y=y-alpha*df(y) having no effect

Comment: Alright guys, thanks for giving me some sanity. It was def the algorithm. Just some minor errors floating around. Of course the mathematician wants to blame it on the computer :P.  Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am simplifying the problem to precision: when you use Decimal you get good precision.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> a = [1.2,1.2]
>>> b = [-2.65765056e-22,9.20132910e-23]
>>> a = [Decimal(i) for i in a]
>>> b = [Decimal(i) for i in b]
>>> a
[Decimal('1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875'), Decimal('1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875')]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> b
[Decimal('-2.657650560000000049520705664376562101548279121350202517182008919716107442354768863879144191741943359375E-22'), Decimal('9.2013290999999997555711266729024269198128893250699076740068186285037565852462648763321340084075927734375E-23')]
>>>
>>> a[0]-b[0]
Decimal('1.199999999999999955591344780')
```

**Alternative solution**: using np.float128

```
>>> a = [1.2,1.2]
>>> b = [-2.65765056e-22,9.20132910e-23]
>>>np.float(a[0]-b[0])
1.2
>>>np.float128(a[0]-b[0])
1.1999999999999999556
```

Comment: My solution was not floating point problems, but if it was, this would have fixed it. Thanks for your answer.